# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate when creating plot in loop

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to make multiple line in lineplot with loop like this but it returns `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. Why it returns that error and how to fix this?

```
plt.figure()
cases = pd.DataFrame(data=covid[['date','acc_released','acc_deceased','acc_negative','acc_confirmed']])
for col in cases.columns:
    sns.lineplot(x=cases['date'],y=covid[col],data=cases)
```

Without loop it will be like this, which is not efficient but works fine

```
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x=covid['date'], y=covid['acc_confirmed'])
sns.lineplot(x=covid['date'], y=covid['acc_deceased'])
sns.lineplot(x=covid['date'], y=covid['acc_negative'])
sns.lineplot(x=covid['date'], y=covid['acc_released'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(['acc_confirmed', 'acc_deceased', 'acc_negative', 'acc_released'],
            loc='upper left')
plt.title('Numbers of cases')
```

This is my data

```
         date  acc_released  acc_deceased  acc_negative  acc_confirmed
0  2020-03-02             0             0           335              2
1  2020-03-03             0             0           337              2
2  2020-03-04             0             0           356              2
3  2020-03-05             0             0           371              2
4  2020-03-06             0             0           422              4
5  2020-03-07             0             0           422              4
```

It's supposed to look this way

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the date as your index you can pass the df to data;

```
sns.lineplot(data=cases)
```

to change the index;

```
df.index = df['Time']
```

then you can drop the time column;

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Time'])
```